# Vue component for Game Die (dice)

Tags: javascript, game, unit-testing, dice, vue.js

As part of learning Vue and Vue Test Utils I develop some simple games. I made a simple version of craps. Because in many other games a die (or dice) is used, I decided to create a reusable component `GameDie`.

**`GameDie.vue`**

```
<template>
  <span class="dice">{{ dice.icon }}</span>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'GameDie',
  data() {
    return {
      dieFaces: [
        {
          value: undefined,
          icon: '',
        },
        {
          value: 1,
          icon: '⚀',
        },
        {
          value: 2,
          icon: '⚁',
        },
        {
          value: 3,
          icon: '⚂',
        },
        {
          value: 4,
          icon: '⚃',
        },
        {
          value: 5,
          icon: '⚄',
        },
        {
          value: 6,
          icon: '⚅',
        },
      ],
      value: undefined,
    };
  },
  computed: {
    dice() {
      return this.dieFaces.filter((el) => el.value === this.value).shift();
    },
  },
  methods: {
    /**
     * Generate a random number between 1 and 6.
     * Assign it to the property value.
     */
    throwDice() {
      this.value = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
      this.$eventBus.$emit('transmit-dice', this.value);
    },
    /**
     * Reset the dice.
     */
    resetDice() {
      if (this.value) {
        this.value = undefined;
      }
    },
  },
  created() {
    this.$eventBus.$on('throw-dice', this.throwDice);
    this.$eventBus.$on('reset-dice', this.resetDice);
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
  .dice {
    font-size: 4em;
  }
</style>
```

I use emojis for the dice. When the die is thrown the value is calculated with `Math.random`. The component relies on a global event bus.

My `main.js` looks like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import { BootstrapVue } from 'bootstrap-vue';
import App from './App.vue';

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css';

Vue.use(BootstrapVue);

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

Vue.prototype.$eventBus = new Vue();

new Vue({
  render: (h) => h(App),
}).$mount('#app');
```

The `GameDie.vue` component can now be used for different games, for craps or backgammon you need two dices:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <game-die></game-die>
    <game-die></game-die>
  </div>
</template>
```

For yamb you would need for example 5 dice, for *Mensch ärgere Dich nicht* just one.

Since I didn't have any other idea I used a global event bus to trigger the throwing and resetting the die. If we include `GameDie.vue` as a child component then the parent should actually communicate with it by passing props. But I was not sure how could I implement this.

The unit tests are here:

```
import { expect } from 'chai';
import sinon from 'sinon';
import mergeWith from 'lodash.mergewith';
import { shallowMount, createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils';
import Vue from 'vue';
import GameDie from '@/components/GameDie.vue';

/* eslint-disable no-param-reassign */
const GlobalPlugins = {
  install(v) {
    v.prototype.$eventBus = new Vue();
  },
};
/* eslint-enable no-param-reassign */
const localVue = createLocalVue();
localVue.use(GlobalPlugins);

describe('GameDie.vue', () => {
  function createWrapper(overrides) {
    const options = {
      mocks: {
        $eventBus: {
          $on: sinon.spy(),
          $emit: sinon.spy(),
        },
      },
    };
    return shallowMount(GameDie, mergeWith(options, overrides));
  }

  it('should render the dice', () => {
    const wrapper = createWrapper();
    expect(wrapper.text()).to.equal('');
  });

  it('should render a die face', () => {
    const data = () => ({
      value: 2,
    });
    const wrapper = createWrapper({ data });
    expect(wrapper.vm.value).to.equal(2);
    expect(wrapper.text()).to.equal('⚁');
  });

  it('should listen to custom events', () => {
    const wrapper = createWrapper();
    expect(wrapper.vm.$eventBus.$on.calledTwice).to.equal(true);
    expect(wrapper.vm.$eventBus.$on.calledWith('throw-dice')).to.equal(true);
    expect(wrapper.vm.$eventBus.$on.calledWith('reset-dice')).to.equal(true);
  });

  it('should listen to custom event throw-dice', () => {
    const throwDiceSpy = sinon.spy();
    const wrapper = shallowMount(GameDie, {
      localVue,
      methods: {
        throwDice: throwDiceSpy,
      },
    });
    wrapper.vm.$eventBus.$emit('throw-dice');
    expect(throwDiceSpy.called).to.equal(true);
  });

  it('should listen to custom event reset-dice', () => {
    const resetDiceSpy = sinon.spy();
    const wrapper = shallowMount(GameDie, {
      localVue,
      methods: {
        resetDice: resetDiceSpy,
      },
    });
    wrapper.vm.$eventBus.$emit('reset-dice');
    expect(resetDiceSpy.called).to.equal(true);
  });

  it('should emit a custom event transmit-dice', () => {
    const wrapper = createWrapper();
    wrapper.vm.throwDice();
    expect(wrapper.vm.$eventBus.$emit.called).to.equal(true);
  });
});
```

What can be improved here? Is there a better way using props? Or maybe Vue.js is not an adequate tool for programming games?

For the unit tests I used the input from a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60338721/how-to-test-a-global-event-bus-in-vuejs) I posted on StackOverflow. If the approach with the global event bus is good, how would you enhance the tests?

Comment: Oh there's definitely nothing wrong with using Vue.js for programming games. I've done so myself for a few games.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, communicating through father-son relation component-wise should be with the event bus and props whereas it is recommended to send events from father to son with props.

I would use a prop to change the specific instance of the dice because you will be triggering a single event to a single die.
If you would indeed want this to happen, I would use a single data property to bind all the dice from the father component.

With your implementation - all dice would reset/re-roll and you would get unknown behavior in the future if you would want to re-use your die.
This would be a bad practice and you want to implement components as a single monad with a designed functionality without side effects. (more on monads [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(functional_programming)))

Secondly I would stick with 'die' or 'dice' for the sake of consistency and readability.

Thirdly, Vue has $emit as a native prototype so there's no need to configure it in your main.js you probably already know it but here's the [resource](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html).
Also, a bit petty but alas, You're not using Bootstrap but you are importing it to your project.

**PS**

Another solution would be using [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) for non father-son relation, perhaps holding an array of dice and changing their state that would trigger a single event for the responsible die

**Edit**

Here's a working git [example of using props with your code](https://github.com/Natanhel/GameDiceExample)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Unfortunately the GitHub repository seems to have just the boilerplate code for a Vue.JS app. Have you maybe forgotten to push the actual code?

Comment: Yes you are correct, no idea how that happened :S
Fixed that :)